# Timestamp in android has the wrong timezone

Tags: android, date, unix, timezone, timestamp

I have a problem with the timestamp. I get a timestamp out of a json  response,this time-stamp is utc time. But this is wrong, the timezone is Berlin. is there any resolution to say that this timestamp is an other timezone?

Comment: are you trying get time from a response, if so try giving you timezone in the link and get the response corresponding to that time zone, dunno whether, you are trying to achieve the same if not ignore

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the people working on the API to return the timezone of the timestamp in the json. Otherwise if you are sure it's UTC every time you can convert it to your timezone.

Comment: how can I convert the time from UTC to berlintime?